# ws-security - set different username and password in every request

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, ws-security, wss4j

I'm using Apache-CXF to create my web service client that uses ws-security with a `UsernameToken`authentification.

In order to use the same credentials for every request I just add the following properties to my `BindingProvider`(i.e. the ws-port):

```
    Map<String, Object> ctx = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
    ctx.put(SecurityConstants.USERNAME, "myUserName");
    ctx.put(SecurityConstants.PASSWORD, "myPassword");
```

However, how can I set a different user and password on every request? Is it possible to add some kind of supplier function to the `UsernameTokenInterceptor` to provide the credential on a per-thread basis (e.g. by readinig them out of a `ThreadLocal` variable)?

As workaround I implemented a `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` that modifies the `Username` and `Password` value in the `Security/UsernameToken` part of the `SOAPHeader`. However, I'd prefer to either add an existing `SOAPHandler` that creates the whole security section or to provide a supplier function to the `UsernameTokenInterceptor`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a UsernameTokenInterceptor? Just use the generated client from cxf and fetch the stub from it and then modify that.

Something along the lines of:

```
public yourResponse call(final String username, final String password) {
    final YourService service = new YourService();
    final YourStub stub = service.getService();

    final Map ctx = ((BindingProvider)stub).getRequestContext();

    ctx.put("ws-security.username", username);
    ctx.put("ws-security.password", password);

    return stub.callYourMethod(); 
}
```

So you can put this in a method and pass username and password and hence you can change it anytime.